# turn off view engine doesn't work in express 4

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I create my app start using express generator, by doing express myApp. So I plan to setup angularjs for my front end. I end up getting this error in my console:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. 
at new View (...\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:41:42)
```

I think it's cause by these 2 line, I commented it out.

```
/*app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');*/
```

I don't
 need the view folder with jade template inside it, because I'm using angularjs. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I guess you need to change `render` method inside your routes, 'cause they try to call view engine

Answer (score 0):

Express expects that you either specify the view with its extension:

`res.render('index.html');`

Or specify a default view engine and name your views after it:

`app.set('view engine', jade');`

and if you are working with `Angular` then I think you will send `response` as `JSON` format, in that case, it also work

like send

`res.send({name:"jack"})`